# OrderBy embedded documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to order my results by the value in an embedded document.

Consider a model such as:

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
}

public class Passenger
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to query my `Car` collection, and order by Passenger.Age

My query looks something like:

```
var results = (from car in _db.GetCollection<Car>("car").AsEnumerable()
              from passenger in car.Passengers
              where car.Name == "Ford"
              orderby passenger.Age).ToList();
```

With this, I get the following exception:

> The SelectMany query operator is not supported.

This is understandably a limitation of the C# mongo driver.
Is there a workaround?

Failing that, how could I order them after my .ToList() ?

Comment: do I understand you correctly if I say that you're trying to get both the Car object and the Passanger object out from your result?

Comment: I believe he's trying to get a list of all the passengers in Fords, by age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably re-write this with `AsQueryable()` to get an `IEnumerable` collection from `ToList()` back, from which you can then further query with any LINQ you want to use, not just the operations directly supported by the `MongoCollection`:

```
var passengers = _db.GetCollection<Car>("car").AsQueryable().ToList()
    .Where(car => car.Name == "Ford")
    .SelectMany(ford => ford.Passengers)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Age);
```

Here's where you can find the [directly supported LINQ operations for the MongoDb C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial#CSharpDriverLINQTutorial-SupportedLINQqueryoperators).